# The Frattini subgroup if no maximal subgroups are present

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

On [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frattini_subgroup) I read that

> For the case that G has no maximal subgroups, for example the trivial group  or the Prüfer group, it is defined by Φ(G) = G.

But such a property would contradict a well-known property of Frattini subgrops, namely that it contains just "non-generators", i.e.

> If $G = H\Phi(G)$ for some $H \le G$, then $G = H$.

But if $G = \Phi(G)$, this would immediately imply $G = 1$ as $G = 1\cdot \Phi(G)$, i.e. the group is trivial.

So I guess the only meaningful way to define $\Phi(G)$ if $G$ has no maximal subgroup would be $\Phi(G) = 1$? Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: But $C_p$ does have a maximal subgroup, the trivial subgroup. All finite groups apart from the trivial group have maximal subgroups.

Comment: Yes. Thank you, I overlooked that! Anyway, the definition $\Phi(G) = G$ still contradicts the property $G = H\Phi(G)$ implies $G = H$.

Comment: So this property just makes sense in the finite case?

Comment: That property only holds for finite groups (or perhaps finitely generated groups). In the proof, you say if not then $H$ is contained in some maximal subgroup of $G$, which is not necessarily true in infinite groups (but I think it works in finitely generated groups).